# Could not find driver PDOException in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am using `xampp` and building a project in `Yii2`. I am getting below error

> "Caused by: PDOException could not find driver in D:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php at line 602".

I also uncommented `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`  in `php.ini` file, but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem.In php.ini file previously extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll was commented. I uncommented that and now its working.